# Bison parse global variables and functions

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, bison

I'm building a compiler for fun, and I'm currently stuck at How to parse when multiple global variables or function definitions are in a single file f.e.

```
int a;
int b;

int main(){
    int c;
}
```

my bison file (simplified) looks like this:

```
ROOT : GLOB { printf("%s\n", "ACCEPTED" }
     ;

VAR_DEC // Assume this matches correctly

FUNC_DEF // Assume this matches correctly

GLOB_STMNT : VAR_DEC {  }
           | FUNC_DEF {  }
           ; 

GLOB_LIST : GLOB_LIST GLOB_STMNT {  }
          | GLOB_STMNT {  }
          ;

GLOB : GLOB_LIST {  }
     ;
```

My problem here is, it will allways only reduce the firstvar declaration and then print accepted. Any idea on how to refine the last 3 rules so it will reduce all 3 global statements?

Comment: Why don't you ad print statements for all the rules? It can show what is going on. Can you also show a script on which it happens? We might also want to see the lexer definitions.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I do have print statements, and according to them everything gets lexed correctly and the grammars almost accordingly. It's really just that bit that's causing trouble.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I'm sorry, I have to apologize, you were right I had an error in a different Rule. I forgot to check for the semicolons lol

Comment: Why do you think it's only reducing the first declaration?  It will parse (and reduce) all the `GLOB_STMNT` in order (which print nothing), and (only) then reduce `ROOT` and print your message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "The algorithm used by the yacc parser encourages so-called left recursive grammar rules. Rules of the following form match this algorithm:

```
    seq : item 
        | seq item 
        ;
```

> The first rule is reduced for the first item only; and the second rule is reduced for the second and all succeeding items."

So you should write your rule as:

```
GLOB_LIST : GLOB_STMNT {  }
          | GLOB_LIST GLOB_STMNT {  }
          ;
```

Comment: This still doesn't work it only reduces using the first rule from your given rules

Comment: Okay my bad, I had some error parsing the var_decs lol, so it worked